# tkinter opens on main pc instead of pi when shelling in

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, raspberry-pi, x11

I have been working to shell into my pi from a laptop and open a gui written with tkinter. My ultimate goal is to be able to shell into the pi from my laptop and type in some text from my laptop and have it display in a GUI on the Pi monitor. The program I made is working great when I open it on the pi from the pi terminal, but when I open it from the ssh from the laptop with x11 forwarding enabled, it opens the gui program on my laptop display instead of on the Pi Display. Could anyone help me understand why, or does anyone have a better idea of how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance for all your help!

(This is the code btw)

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("400x200")

Font_tuple = ("Comic Sans MS", 15, "bold")
e = tk.Entry(window, justify = 'center')
e.configure(bg='white', font = Font_tuple)
window.configure(bg='black')
e.place(x = 325,
        y = 400,
        width = 900, 
        height = 40)
e.pack

width= window.winfo_screenwidth()
height= window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
window.title("Escape Fond du Lac")

while True:
    textcommand = input('Enter Your Text: ')
    e.delete(0, END)
    file2write=open("hinttext.txt",'w')
    file2write.write(str(textcommand))
    file2write.close()

    file = open("hinttext.txt", 'r')

    content = file.read()

    e.insert(0,content)
    
mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use something like VNC viewer to remotely connect to the rpi desktop.

Comment: Assuming you have permission to do so, you can set `DISPLAY=:0` in your environment, or add `-display :0` as a command line parameter.

Comment: _"when I open it from the ssh from the laptop with x11 forwarding enabled, it opens the gui program on my laptop display instead of on the Pi Display."_ - that's exactly what x11 forwarding is supposed to do.

Comment: Disabe X11 forwarding when ssh to Pi.

Comment: @acw1668 If I don't use X11 forwarding I get an error when trying to run the program from ssh

Comment: You need to set environment `DISPLAY=:0` if the X11 is running on display :0 in the Pi.  Or run  your code like `DISPLAY=:0 python ...`.

Comment: @acw1668 So that would make the GUI appear on the Pi instead of my laptop?

Comment: @Isaiahlucas Simply try it yourself and you will know.