# Is there any way to display GUI on a different device when using x11?

Tags: python, tkinter, ssh, raspberry-pi, x11

I was wondering if there is any way to display a GUI on my Raspberry Pi instead of my computer when I ssh into it from my computer with x11? I've tried reading documentation but haven't found anything. If you could offer any help that would be awesome! Thanks!

This is my code btw.

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("400x200")

Font_tuple = ("Comic Sans MS", 15, "bold")
e = tk.Entry(window, justify = 'center')
e.configure(bg='white', font = Font_tuple)
window.configure(bg='black')
e.place(x = 325,
        y = 400,
        width = 900, 
        height = 40)
e.pack

width= window.winfo_screenwidth()
height= window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
window.title("Escape Fond du Lac")

while True:
    textcommand = input('Enter Your Text: ')
    e.delete(0, END)
    file2write=open("hinttext.txt",'w')
    file2write.write(str(textcommand))
    file2write.close()

    file = open("hinttext.txt", 'r')

    content = file.read()

    e.insert(0,content)
    
    
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use the `DISPLAY` environment variable to tell X11 what device to display on.

Comment: @Barmar. Do I have to type in a certain thing?

Comment: `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` before running the python script.

Comment: That assumes the RPi has its own display and you're running an X server on it.

Comment: [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69139634/tkinter-opens-on-main-pc-instead-of-pi-when-shelling-in) has been asked, why don't you update the question instead of creating duplicate question?

Comment: Yes, I think that's exactly what I said

Comment: @Barmar, Do I have to have an X server on my RPi as well?

Comment: Of course, how else will it display the output?

Comment: Presumably you have a keyboard, a mouse and a monitor connected to your RasPi? So login to your RasPi using them first, then `ssh` in and run your script as Barmar suggested.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the only problem with that is the program is written in Tkinter and it gives me an error when I don't use x11

Comment: All X11 programs work much the same, so you should be able to `ssh` into your RasPi and do `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` and then run `xclock` and it should display on your RasPi screen. See if that works, because if it does, Tkinter will likely work the same way.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I keep getting this error, Can't open display: localhost:0.0

Comment: Try logging into your RasPi using its own keyboard+mouse+monitor and running `xhost +` to allow anyone to connect to the display. Do this before  `ssh`ing into the RasPi from your Mac.